# What does "cease to be never" means?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, religion

The line is from a translation of [Bhagavad Gita by Sir Edwin Arnold](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Bhagavad_Gita_(Arnold_translation)/Chapter_2):

> Never the spirit was born; the spirit shall **cease to be never;**
>   Never was time it was not; End and Beginnings are dreams!
>   ....

Comment: It is *the spirit never ceases to be* regardless of what the guy wrote.

Comment: The spirit shall come to an end or die out  never = Never will a time be without spirit = The spirit will never cease to be.

Answer (score 3):

[Sir Edwin Arnold](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Author:Edwin_Arnold) (1832–1904) translated the *Bhagavad Gita* in 1885. His versification is antique in style. I don't speak Sanskrit, but perhaps there is some similarity in the structure of phrases; but maybe not: he may simply have wanted to sound ancient and portentous.

Here, *be* is used in the sense "exist", much as Shakespeare does in Hamlet's "To be or not to be" soliloquy. *Never* is simply an adverb whose position is unusual when compared to modern English.

> The spirit shall cease to be never
>   → The spirit shall never cease to be
>   → The spirit shall never cease to exist.

The whole extract is speaking of the eternal nature of the spirit, never born and always existing.

In "never was time it was not", the second *was* also means *existed*:

> Never was time it was not
>   → Never was time it did not exist
>   → There was never a time when it did not exist